# Gremlin Java and querying

Tags: java, graph-databases, gremlin

I'm a bit confused about Gremlin in Java.  
As I understand I have 2 different ways of querying:

```
graph.query().has("firstName", "Joan").has("lastName", "G").vertices()
```

or:

```
new GremlinPipeline(graph.getVertices("firstName", "Joan")).has("lastName", "G").cast(Vertex.class).toList()
```

I quiet like the first one but why we don't get the all benefits of a GremlinPipeline, filter, select, as, back... ?
In other words why .query() is not returning a GremlinPipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.query()` is the core API. Under the hood GremlinPipeline uses this API to chain your steps together. Usually I only use `.query()` when I have a 1-level-depth traversal without filters.

Cheers,
Daniel